# php HTTP_ORIGIN not set

Tags: php, cors

I am trying to implement CORS using php using the following code

```php
//will add domains in this array
$allowedOrigins = array();

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] != '') {
  foreach ($allowedOrigins as $allowedOrigin) {
    if (preg_match('#' . $allowedOrigin . '#', $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
      header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
      header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
      header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');
      header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] returns nothing (empty string)
Is there any alternative for HTTP_ORIGIN ?
OR am I doing anything wrong ?

Comment: Are you *sending* an `Origin` header in the request?

Comment: We are using angularJS as our frontend which sends origin by default.

Comment: Alright. Have you tried `var_dump($_SERVER)` to see if it might have been renamed to something else?

Comment: There is no key named HTTP_ORIGIN. It isn't renamed.
I have searched the internet, implementing cors needs HTTP_ORIGIN, evey code uses that.